# Evitar que la pagina cambie de tamaño al abrir el teclado del navegador

Tags: html

Tengo el problema de que al abrir el teclado del navegador movil, la pagina cambia de tamaño, hace zoom y toda la pagina se aplasta ¿hay forma de evitar esto?
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Añade el html y/o css que refiere a los elementos afectados para poder entender tu problema.

Answer (score 0):

Normalmente si no usas `Jquery mobile` tendrás que arreglar manualmente todo tipo de bugs. Si quieres hacerlo sin jquery tendrás que escuchar al `viewport resize change event` y mediante escucharlo obtener el ancho y alto restante del viewport.

inicia una función acoplandote al cambio del viewport:

```
$(window).resize(function() 
{

});
```

y dentro de la función obtén el ancho y alto y ajusta la altura y la anchura conforme al layout.

```
$(window).resize(function() 
{

   var viewportWidth = $(window).width();

   var viewportHeight = $(window).height();

   //cambio del layout aqui.

});
```